# How does xsd:any ##other behave when part of an extension

Tags: xsd

When extending the Oasis BaseFaultType from another xsd of a different namespace would the xsd:any ##other by default put all of the extended class members within it?
This is the relevant part of Oasis BaseFaultType

```html
  <xsd:element name="BaseFault" type="wsrf-bf:BaseFaultType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="BaseFaultType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
      <xsd:element name="Timestamp" type="xsd:dateTime" />
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Originator" type="wsa:EndpointReferenceType" />
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorCode">
```

And here is the example of the extension

```html
<xsd:schema xmlns:ws-bf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:cmn="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" xmlns:tns="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" version="1.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./bf-2.xsd" namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" />
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./Meta.xsd" namespace="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" />
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./CodeLists.xsd" namespace="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" />
  <xsd:element name="Fault" type="tns:FaultType">
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="FaultType">
    <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xsd:extension base="ws-bf:BaseFaultType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="xsd:normalizedString">
          </xsd:element>
```

Which is part of a parent XSD

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:cmn="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" xmlns:tns="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1" xmlns:vfo="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1" version="1.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./Fault.xsd" namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" />
  <xsd:element name="Source" type="tns:SourceType" />
  <xsd:element name="Destination" type="tns:DestinationType" />
  <xsd:element name="Correlation" type="tns:CorrelationType" />
  <xsd:element name="Cache" type="tns:CacheType" />
  <xsd:element name="ServiceDocumentation" type="tns:ServiceDocumentationType" />
  <xsd:element name="ResultStatus" type="vfo:FaultType" />
```

What I need is an XSD expert to tell me if this complies to W3C standard when the xml response expected is as follows :

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <tns:ResultStatus xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:vfo="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" xmlns:cmn="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:ns1="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:standard:CoreComponentType:2" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1">
      <vfo:Name>1006</vfo:Name>
      <vfo:Message>Invalid ChargeAccountNumber (not found).</vfo:Message>
      <ns2:Timestamp>2017-06-19T10:18:48.467+01:00</ns2:Timestamp>
   </tns:ResultStatus>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In this cut for brevity example, would the Name value belong to the Any structure of BaseFaultType or the parent extension FaultType? And if not, why not?
Are there any tools that would allow me to report on the validity of the response against the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BaseFault cannot be extended outside of its own namespace. The flaw was never corrected during early design :
https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/wsrf/200506/msg00060.html